# How to prevent rows from shifting when syncing with main data source?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am creating a directory of people in a group. In the first sheet are the names, address, phone, and email info. The basics.

Then in Sheet 2 I am keeping a record of attendance.

In the third sheet I am keeping a record of some goals that are accomplished.

I used `=ARRAYFORMULA(BASE!A:A)` to get the first column and put that in the second and third sheets.

This worked great for a while. Then we got a new member. I added their info to the base sheet. His name was brought over to the second and third sheet. That's good. But it didn't keep the rows connected on the second and third sheet. They were off by one row since adding the new member shifted the cells that he was added on.

SO...

Base Sheet

```
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|First Name    | Last Name  | Address    | and so on......  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|John          | Doe        | 123 Main   |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|Jim           | Smith      | 123 Elm    |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|Jill          | Summers    | 123 Aspen  |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
```

Then I have another sheet for tracking attendance taking the first name and last name from the base sheet.
The top row and first two columns are frozen on both sheets.

```
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| First Name   | Last Name  | 10/1/19    | 10/7/19 | and so on.....|
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| John         | Doe        | x          | x       |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| Jim          | Smith      |            | x       |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| Jill         | Summers    | x          |         |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
```

What  I would like to do is be able to add a new row for a new name and it create a new row in the secondary sheets as well. For example...

```
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|First Name    | Last Name  | Address    | and so on......  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|John          | Doe        | 123 Main   |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|Julie         | Fry        | 123 Oak    |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|Jim           | Smith      | 123 Elm    |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
|Jill          | Summers    | 123 Aspen  |                  |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------------|
```

which would result in ...

```
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| First Name   | Last Name  | 10/1/19    | 10/7/19 | and so on.....|
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| John         | Doe        | x          | x       |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| Julie        | Fry        |            |         |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| Jim          | Smith      |            | x       |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
| Jill         | Summers    | x          |         |               |
|--------------|------------|------------|---------|---------------|
```

Is there a way to fix this situation? Or perhaps just a better way to do this?

I know I could add the name to the bottom of the list and that would "kinda" work, but then I wouldn't be able to sort by first of last name. The sort would work on the base page, but it would also sort the name on the attendance page, but the data in the rows would be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to lock it down with `INDIRECT` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("BASE!B:B"))
```

Comment: gave it a shot. didn't seem to have an effect.